# How to change theme ( light to dark) during run time?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have already defined both themes in styles.xml. How do i implement it? (I am new to android so a detailed answer would be highly appreciated )
Thanks!

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667743/how-do-i-change-to-a-holo-dark-light-themes-from-within-the-app` .check out that..