# Is there any proper way to change colors in resource (colors.xml) file programmatically in android

Tags: android, themes

I've set different colors in different layout files which I need to change in runtime for lite/dark app color mode. Is there any way I can change color programmatically which takes effect in those layout files? 
I can change resource color like below:

```
public class CustomResources extends Resources {

private static final String TAG = "CustomResources";
private Context context;

public CustomResources(Resources original, Context context) {
    super(original.getAssets(), original.getDisplayMetrics(), original.getConfiguration());
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getColor(int id) throws NotFoundException {
    return getColor(id, null);
}

@Override
public int getColor(int id, Theme theme) throws NotFoundException {
    if (Prefs.getInstance(context).getBooleanValue(AppConstants.IS_DARK_THEME)) {

        switch (getResourceEntryName(id)) {

            case "color_for_font_size_regular":
                return Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF");

            case "colorWhite":
                return Color.parseColor("#262626");

            default:
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    return super.getColor(id, theme);
                } else return super.getColor(id);
        }
    } else {
        switch (getResourceEntryName(id)) {
            default:
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    return super.getColor(id, theme);
                } else return super.getColor(id);
        }
    }
}
```

}

And use this in Activity:

```
private CustomResources res;

@Override
public Resources getResources() {
    if (res == null) {
        res = new CustomResources(super.getResources(), this);
    }
    return res;
}
```

This code segment works if I set color for every view in java. But I need it to work when I set colors in layout files only. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change to a Holo Dark/Light themes from within the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667743/how-do-i-change-to-a-holo-dark-light-themes-from-within-the-app)

Comment: Not really. If you please read the explanation.

Comment: Try to use attributes. For example, use ?colorPrimary instead of @color/primaryColor  then by changing the theme on runtime, anything that uses ?primaryColor attribute, its color changed according to the current set theme.https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes

Comment: @AmirHossein hey man, thanks a lot. This works for my case which I didn't get at first attempt. If you want, you can add this as answer so that I can accept it as correct answer. 